# How old was Ezra when he came to Jerusalem?

Tags: ezra, babylon

> <sup>**1**</sup>Now after these things, in the reign of Artaxerxes king of Persia, Ezra the son of Seraiah, the son of Azariah, the son of Hilkiah, <sup>**2**</sup> The son of Shallum, the son of Zadok, the son of Ahitub, <sup>**3**</sup> The son of Amariah, the son of Azariah, the son of Meraioth, <sup>**4**</sup> The son of Zerahiah, the son of Uzzi, the son of Bukki, <sup>**5**</sup> The son of Abishua, the son of Phinehas, the son of Eleazar, the son of Aaron the chief priest: <sup>**6**</sup> This Ezra went up from Babylon; and he was a ready scribe in the law of Moses, which the Lord God of Israel had given: and the king granted him all his request, according to the hand of the Lord his God upon him. <sup>**7**</sup> And there went up some of the children of Israel, and of the priests, and the Levites, and the singers, and the porters, and the Nethinims, unto Jerusalem, in the seventh year of Artaxerxes the king. <sup>**8**</sup> And he came to Jerusalem in the fifth month, which was in the seventh year of the king. (Ezra 7:1-8)

How old was Ezra when he came to Jerusalem?

Comment: We are not told

Answer (score 1):

**How old was Ezra when he came to Jerusalem?**

Good question. I could only find something in [Coffman's](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/bcc/ezra.html) Commentaries related to the span of time around Ezra. Maybe there's something here that can help?

[image]

Sorry, I don't know how much assistance this might offer you.

Answer (score 1):

**How old was Ezra when he came to Jerusalem?**

According to the Jewish Virtual Library, Ezra was **born in 480 BC** and died in 440 BC.

In the **7th regnal year of Artaxerxes I** (Mar/April to Mar/April of 457/58 BC), at the beginning of the 7th year, in the month of Nisan, Ezra had his request to the king conceded, to lead a consortium of Jews and go back to Jerusalem, in order to...

"study the law of the (ultimate) Lord, and to practice it, and to teach His statutes and ordinances in Israel" **Ezra 7:10 NASB.**

Ezra had to have been around 23 years old, which according to some scholars would have been too young to have been a legitimate scribe/priest, although he apparently was just that. The journey (according to Ryrie's notes in the NASB study bible) lasted from Mar 27 to July 24, and therefore ended in the month of Ab.